# localhost ha rechazado la conexión

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2019, bootstrap-5

Tengo un proyecto web nuevo en VS 2019, lo primero que he hecho es comprobar si funcionaba correctamente ejecutandolo varias veces, la web carga correctamente, pero, al tener bootstrap 3 decidí actualizarlo, a partir de ese momento, cuando cierro el IDE y lo vuelvo a abrir, depuro la web y lo carga correctamente, pero si paro la ejecución y vuelvo a cargarlo me devuelve:

[image: error de acceso localhost]

He buscado al respecto pero no encuentro un problema similar al mío, se de la existencia de un problema de compatibilidad entre bootstrap 5 y BundleConfig, es por ello que he eliminado el bundle y he creado en su lugar:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Lo que me llama la atención es que tengo que cerrar completamente Visual Studio y me hace sospechar que la instancia de IISExpress se queda levantada, pero no logro encontrar el motivo de esta, ya que si creo un proyecto en blanco, esto no ocurre, solo ocurre en el momento de actualizar Bootstrap.

¿Cómo se puede solucionar esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se exactamente cómo, pero está solucionado.

He probado todo lo posible. Desinstalar y reinstalar IIS Express, actualizar Visual Studio, borrar applicationhost.config...

Al final he accedido a:

- Depurar / opciones.
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He marcado la opción "Usar la versión 64 bits" y justo después he ido a las propiedades del proyecto, en Web/depuradores he desmarcado "Habilitar editar y continuar", he ejecutado varias veces, el problema ya no existe.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]